# [Python2.7 TKinter]How to gray out a option in optionmenu that has been selected by older instances?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

Here's my code:

```
class DefaultServiceClassWidget(ServiceClassWidget):
    def __init__(self, mpet_widget, sc_data, idx):
        super(DefaultServiceClassWidget, self).__init__(mpet_widget, sc_data, idx, DefaultServiceClassRow.number)

        delete_default_sc_button = Button(mpet_widget.listFrame,justify=LEFT,text="x",fg="red",command= lambda: mpet_widget.delete_sc(self.idx))
        delete_default_sc_button.grid(column=4,row=DefaultServiceClassRow.number)

        self.select_default_class_label = Label(mpet_widget.listFrame,anchor=W,justify=LEFT,text="Select a Class")
        self.select_default_class_label.grid(column=0,row=DefaultServiceClassRow.number)

        options = ["All","CS Registration","GPRS Attach","PDP Activation","SMS","Reset","USSD","LTE"]
        self.menu_pick_a_class = OptionMenu(mpet_widget.listFrame, sc_data.get_name(), *options, command=lambda event: sc_data.set_id())
        self.menu_pick_a_class.grid(column=1,row=DefaultServiceClassRow.number)
        self.row = DefaultServiceClassRow.number
        DefaultServiceClassRow.number = DefaultServiceClassRow.number+2

    def delete(self):
        DefaultServiceClassRow.number = DefaultServiceClassRow.number - 2
        default_list = (list(self.mpet_widget.listFrame.grid_slaves(row=self.row)) +
                        list(self.mpet_widget.listFrame.grid_slaves(row=self.row+1)))
        for l in default_list:
            l.grid_remove()
```

What happens is that there's a button connected to this function, every time the button is clicked, this function gets called and created a new grid on the GUI. What I want is that if for example "SMS" in optionmenu is selected, the next time this function gets called, "SMS" option will be grayed out (i.e. each option can be only selected once in the program)

I've tried updating status of the selected option by using status = "disabled" but it only works for the same grid, once a new grid(instance) is created, everything gets reset and all the options became available again :(

Also, in the same grid, if I disabled an option by selecting it and then changed to something else, the original selection is still grayed and cannot be selected again - I know why this happens but how do I fix it?

Sorry for the long question but I can't seem to find a solution online :(

Thank you in advance!